# Looking for CRM 2015 sdk zip download

Tags: sdk, dynamics-crm, crm

Few days back I asked by a senior developer to download Microsoft CRM 2015 SDK zip(or even dynamics CRM). Then to extract the zip, open an html file in it which has explanation or sample code data. Now the developer has left and I can't seem to find this zip file that contains such html anywhere online. All I found is exe files from below

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50032
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/download-tools-nuget

Microsoft.CrmDeveloperTools.vsix

and many other sources simply point to this same download on google search. 
Does anyone have any idea what which zip he might be referring to. I really need it to get myself acquainted with CRM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to the CRM 2015 SDK:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44567

Which I got from this page:
https://www.crmanswers.net/p/resources-for-crm-developers.html#CRM2015

And from this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamics/

It appears that the CRM 2015 SDK content is still live online:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2015/developers-guide/gg309408(v=crm.7)